# How to bind to view model object properties?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

We are building a form-based app that has a complex object with many levels of nested properties.

So far, I have created a [simple experiment with a single view model with one object](https://gist.run/?id=a5cc21025caa098fef1b1efb7c79a572). The experiment has fields that are bound to object properties, which successfully display the data. However, when changing the fields, the object does not seem to be updated.

What should I do to make sure form input propagates throughout the view model and into the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use getter method in app.js as below,

```
get swaggerString() {
    console.log(this.swagger);
    const swaggerStringified = JSON.stringify(this.swagger);

    return swaggerStringified;
  }
```

In your HTML, change method to property,

```
 ${swaggerString}
```

Updated your GIST,

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3b85820d66c2dfbf0f770208a7c8b63f

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this. This will cause you to have dirty checking. I'll post a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

What are you planning to do in the real app?

The accepted answer only answers how to solve your problem as posted in the gist. I'm guessing your real app doesn't need to display JSON data.

If you are just wanting to display deeply nested object properties, then that is simple, you simply bind to those properties themselves. See here: https://gist.run/?id=5af5c22be4b49c0e3fef327e3d8b986b

```
<pre>
{
  "name": "${swagger.name}",
  "version": "${swagger.version}"
}
</pre>
```

You can even go arbitrarily deep in to an object tree, e.g. `${foo.bar.baz.ball.foop}`.

The thing to understand is that Aurelia observes for changes to whatever you tell it to observe. When you tell it to simply observe an property that is an object, it can only watch for changes to the property itself. This means it will only see a change if you assign a different object to the property. It does not watch every property on the object for changes for performance reasons (and also due to `Object.observe` being cancelled).

All hope is not lost, though. Please respond with some specifics and I'll try to help you out better.